# Workaround for PHP taking up too much memory when using Reflection class in a loop

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, reflection, memory-leaks

I have a loop like this

```
    foreach ($classes as $class)
    {
        $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($class);
        ... /*code that doesn't matter - commenting it out leaves the
              memory consumption all the same */
    }
```

Which gives the **Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted** result in case of a big number of classes to loop through and relatively small allowed memory size in php.ini (for me that's around **4000** classes and **128 MB** memory setting).

Memory usage right before the loop start is around **1.6 MB**.

As you might guess, leaving `unset($reflectionClass)` at the end of the loop body doesn't help at all.

Upon some googling my guess is that PHP doesn't free the memory taken by the object in case it has some internal references to other objects.
Now, these posts ([one](http://paul-m-jones.com/archives/262), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673460/does-this-cause-a-php-memory-leak), [three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1372211/php-memory-leak-and-fork)) made me try using the garbage collector expicitly:

```
    gc_enable();
    foreach ($classes as $class)
    {
        $reflectionClass = new \ReflectionClass($class);
        ...
        unset($reflectionClass);
        gc_collect_cycles();
    }
```

Which still leads to the same result.

The solutions I see:
1) Increase allowed memory setting - which is ugly and sad.
2) Separate classes into portions and get the needed result from each portion separately via forking or executing some other PHP script - but this sounds like a tough way to go.

Is there a simple workaround for the memory leak? Am I missing something here?

**Update**

Thanks to **Paul Crovella** for pointing out that it is keeping loaded class definitions that takes up memory, and it is in fact not a leak.

So it can be solved either by execution in the child process, or by another script. Added my own solution as an answer.

Comment: The version is 5.4.15. Strange that it's not reproducible for you, I'm persistently getting a +30-130KB increase for each loop, depending on class contents.

Comment: That's a good point, thanks!
At the start of the loop there exists only an array of strings containing class names. Creating a `ReflectionClass` by name surely loads the class definition, but isn't the latter (or *shouldn't it be*) unloaded, specifically after unsetting the object that uses it?

Comment: @PaulCrovella Thanks a lot! You are totally right, I didn't take into account the fact that all those classes are actually hanging there for the rest of life of the PHP instance.
For investigation purposes implemented a hack via forking and sockets (for child processes to return generated data back to the parent process): it is significantly slower, but memory consumption is by couple orders of magnitute less. Don't know whether it's the right solution, and it probably can be optimized, but still solves the main problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Implemented a workaround via delegating processing of portions of classes to child processes, which take all the loaded class definitions down to Hades with them upon exiting.

Looks like this:

```
    foreach (array_chunk($classes, 300) as $classesPortion)
    {
        if (socket_create_pair(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0, $socketArray) === false)
            throw new \Exception('Could not create socket');

        $pid = pcntl_fork();
        if ($pid === -1) //Forking failed
        {
            throw new \Exception('Could not fork process');
        }
        elseif ($pid === 0) //Is child process
        {
            socket_close($socketArray[1]);
            foreach ($classesPortion as $class)
            {
                $data = ...; //generating needed data
            }
            $dataString = serialize($data);
            if (!socket_write($socketArray[0], $dataString, strlen($dataString)))
            {
                throw new \Exception('Failed to write to socket');
            }
            socket_close($socketArray[0]);
            exit(0);
        }
        else //Is parent process
        {
            socket_close($socketArray[0]);
            pcntl_waitpid($pid, $childProcessStatus);
            if ($childProcessStatus !== 0)
            {
                throw new \Exception('Child process exited abnormally');
            }
            else
            {
                $result = socket_read($socketArray[1], 1000000, PHP_BINARY_READ);
                ... // deal with result
            }
            socket_close($socketArray[1]);
        }
    }
```